# How to remove the effect of all the parent containers on any child control

Tags: asp.net, css, html, telerik, datepicker

Q:

I have the following problem , I use `RadDatePicker` in a table `td` and i have more than container(`div`).the problem is the `(next and previous navigation text is reversed)`.
I mean `>>` instead of `<<` and `>` instead of `<` and vice versa.i tried to set the properties related to this issue but in vain .some parent container effect reverse any thing.

When i take the control out of any container every thing goes okay . What i wanna is to remove any effect of the containers' CSS on my date picker.Because i don't know which property exactly make this strange effect.

My source code:

```
<div class="toggle_container">
        <div class="block">
            <h4 align="right" dir="rtl">
               :</h4>
            <hr style="width: 745px;" align="right" />
            <asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel1" runat="server">
                <ContentTemplate>
                    <div id="masterDiv" align="center" style="width: 800px">
                        <div id="masterControls" style="text-align: center; width: 780px;">
                            <table align="center" cellpadding="3" cellspacing="1" width="98%" dir="rtl">
                                <tr bgcolor="#f1ece2">
                                    <th colspan="3" align="right" valign="middle">

                                    </th>
                                </tr>
                                 <%--  more markup --%>
                                <tr bgcolor="#f1ece2">
                                    <td align="right" class="title" colspan="2" style="text-align: center" width="40%">
                                        الفترة (من):
                                    </td>
                                    <td align="right">

                                            <telerik:RadDatePicker ID="rad_dateFrom" runat="server" Culture="Arabic (Egypt)"
                                                Skin="Web20">
                                            </telerik:RadDatePicker>

                                    </td>
                                </tr>
                                <tr bgcolor="#f1ece2">
                                    <td align="right" class="title" colspan="2" style="text-align: center" width="40%">
                                        الفترة (الى):
                                    </td>
                                    <td align="right">
                                        <telerik:RadDatePicker ID="rad_dateTo" runat="server" Culture="Arabic (Egypt)" Skin="Web20">
                                            <Calendar Skin="Web20" UseColumnHeadersAsSelectors="False" UseRowHeadersAsSelectors="False"
                                                ViewSelectorText="x">
                                            </Calendar>
                                            <DatePopupButton HoverImageUrl="" ImageUrl="" />
                                        </telerik:RadDatePicker>
                                    </td>
                                </tr>
                                 <%-- more markup  --%>
                            </table>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                        </ContentTemplate>
                <Triggers>
                </Triggers>
            </asp:UpdatePanel>

        </div>
    </div>
```

From Firebug:

```
<a id="ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_rad_dateFrom_calendar_FNN" class="rcFastNext" href="#" title=">>">&gt;&gt;</a>
```

This is the `fast next navigation` and what has shown to me is `<<` how to convert it to `>>`.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks a lot. the answer is so simple. just the table direction is  `rtl`.and this is the problem.

Answer (score 1):

Inspect the element in question and see what styles have been overwritten. It's hard to say more without live example. Just for the look of your code `writing-mode` comes to mind.

Comment: From Firebug:

`<a id="ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_rad_dateFrom_calendar_FNN" class="rcFastNext" href="#" title=">>">&gt;&gt;</a>`

This is the `fast next navigation` and what has shown to me is `<<` how to convert it to `>>`.